# How to calculate the amplitude of a matter wave of debroglie equation?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, waves, wavelength

I studied the formula that to calculate the wavelength of a matter wave we have to calculate $h/p$ where $h$ is plancks constant and $p$ is the momentum of the particle for which we want to calculate the wave length
wikipedia-link: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matter_wave. And I am wondering how to calculate the amplitude of that wave.

Answer (score 1):

> And I am wondering how to calculate the amplitude of that wave.

You are essentially asking how to calculate the wave
function $\Psi(\vec{r},t)$ of a particle.

Based on [de Broglie's hypotheses](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matter_wave#De_Broglie_relations) ($\vec{p}=\hbar\vec{k}$
and $E=\hbar\omega$) Schrödinger found the [equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schr%C3%B6dinger_equation)
$$i\hbar\frac{\partial}{\partial t}\Psi(\vec{r},t)
=\left(-\frac{\hbar^2}{2m}\vec{\nabla}^2+V(\vec{r})\right)\Psi(\vec{r},t)$$
where $m$ is the mass of the particle and $V(\vec{r})$ is its
potential energy at position $\vec{r}$.

Although Schrödinger's equation was a speculation (guided by
de Broglie's speculation), it turned out to be a direct hit.
It correctly predicts the facts experimentally found.

You can find the wave function $\Psi(\vec{r},t)$
by solving this differential equation.

Some examples:

- A single electron flying through a double slit.
  Here we have
  $$V(\vec{r})=\begin{cases}
    0, &\text{ in free space} \\
    +V_0, &\text{ within the walls}
    \end{cases}$$
- The hydrogen atom (a single electron in the electrical field
  of the atomic nucleus).
  Here we have $$V(\vec{r})=-\frac{e^2}{4\pi\epsilon_0 r}.$$

Then the interpreation of the wave function is that
$|\Psi(\vec{r},t)|^2 d^3r$ gives the probability
of finding the particle within a volume element $d^3r$
at position $\vec{r}$.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, in de Broglie's theory the amplitude was just not considered at all. Later, when quantum mechanics has been developed and made formal, particles have been described by wavefunctions $\psi$. Their amplitude is fixed such that the total probability of finding the particle *anywhere* is

$$\int |\psi(\vec x)|^2 d^3 x=1$$